# How do I get only numbers in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Lets say I have "13 coins". How would extract 13 from that? I tried getting the first 2 numbers but if there was 3 numbers it wouldnt work.

Comment: you could use a regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
"13 coins".replace(/[^0-9.]/g,"")
```

This is what I would usually do (though people may accuse me of using a hammer to kill a fly!). And yes, this works with decimals.

Comment: Humm, that didn't work for my "5e9 is 5 billion" :-)

Comment: Just wanted to point out that this is a terrible solution.  For example extracting the number from the text of "15 roof planks size 4x2" would give me "1542" which is not what I want extracted....

Answer (score 3):

If that is your only example then "parseInt" should work

for example

```js
alert(parseInt("13 coins"));
```

Comment: Is there a way where it would work with decimals?

Comment: @Terry `parseFloat()`

Comment: @thomas thanks alot :)

Comment: Don't forget the radix if you use `parseInt`.

Comment: It's good practice. If you include it you don't need to worry about whether you're supporting ES3 browsers or not.